# Locating the double of a number in a triangular arrangement of the integers?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I write the positive numbers starting at $1$ in a triangle:$$\mathbb{N}_\triangle = \begin{matrix}
    &&&&&21&\ldots         \\
    &&&&15&20&\ldots       \\
    &&&10&14&19&\ldots     \\
    &&6&9&13&18&\ldots   \\
    &3&5&8&12&17&\ldots \\
    1&2&4&7&11&16&\ldots 
    \end{matrix}$$

If $x$ is any number in the $n^{th}-column$ of $\mathbb{N}_\triangle$ in what column can we find $2x$? Can I expect to get a closed formula for this?  I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: The column number of $n$ is the maximal value $k$, for which we have $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\le n$

Comment: Now, I am interested in the same question, but with rows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last number in the $n$th column is $m_l(n) = n(n+1)/2.$

The first number is one more than the last number in the previous column:  $m_f(n) = 1 + n(n-1)/2.$

We can invert the first expression to find the column a particular number of interest $m$ lies in:

$$n(m) = \lceil\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 8m}}{2}\rceil$$

So, given a column $n$, you can find the first and last numbers in that column with the first two formulas, and then use the third formula to determine $n(2m_f)$ and $n(2m_l)$.

Comment: I am not able to follow this perhaps you can work it out with an example?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit very recently.  Is it clearer?

Comment: I'm assuming you're given a column $n$, and want to know which column(s) contain the doubles of the numbers in that column.  Is this correct?

Comment: If I give you the number $13$ which is column $n=5$ I was looking for a formula in $n$ to tell me what column $26$ is located?

Comment: Then just use the last equation and calculate $n(26)$.

Comment: $$n(26) = \bigg{\lceil}{-1+\sqrt{1+8*26} \above 1.5pt 2}\bigg{\rceil} =7$$  And I have that $26$ is in column $7$.

Comment: $n(26) = \lceil(-1+\sqrt{209})/2 \rceil \doteq \lceil13.46/2\rceil = 7.$

Comment: Yep, looks like you've got it!